# Can org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMReader read java.security.PrivateKey?

Tags: java, cryptography, openssl, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption

I have following code:

```
PrivateKey key = null;
X509Certificate cert = null;
KeyPair keyPair = null;

final Reader reader = new StringReader(pem);
try {
    final PEMReader pemReader = new PEMReader(reader, new PasswordFinder() {
        @Override
        public char[] getPassword() {
            return password == null ? null : password.toCharArray();
        }
    });

    Object obj;
    while ((obj = pemReader.readObject()) != null) {
        if (obj instanceof X509Certificate) {
            cert = (X509Certificate) obj;
        } else if (obj instanceof PrivateKey) {
            key = (PrivateKey) obj;
        } else if (obj instanceof KeyPair) {
            keyPair = (KeyPair) obj;
        }
    }
} finally {
    reader.close();
}
```

Will it ever read PrivateKey? In other words, can any PEM file contain pure private key only? If yes, could you provide me a sample PEM file?

Thanks in advace.

Comment: I don't have a sample at hand but as you can read here: http://ospkibook.sourceforge.net/docs/OSPKI-2.4.7/OSPKI-html/sample-priv-key.htm it's possible. (or is this an attempt to get private-keys from people :))

Comment: See also *[Formatting RSA keys for OpenSSL in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3660132/3474).*

Answer (score 7):

A file *can* contain only a private key, and it can be encrypted or clear text. OpenSSL does this all the time.

I reviewed the code for `PEMReader`, however, and it looks like it will return a `KeyPair` from an RSA private key (the private key file contains all the necessary information for the corresponding public key). It looks like it will never return simply a `PrivateKey` from `readObject()`.

Here's an unencrypted 1024 RSA private key from OpenSSL.

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Here's the corresponding public key:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC/oBTZGo0cgHHdZD8LgDpUVOPj
sI58PrTJPtrlVT7kyznmzFEtTW9cqxlw6EOo09tTTrjikLDA2M5xzejbLGPb8sa7
AzVhuHkChgGh9eZmphsnvq1WLjuXCk5yWOR9ziaBKKFeNXOsdvDp3eMDM+wz3vzn
1wrGrg00jMvKP5kcpwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

A `KeyStore` is meant to be used to carry public, private, and symmetric keys in a Java application. Most Java applications store private keys in a PKCS #8 encoding (which is not [the same as the OpenSSL format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3660741/3474)), and public keys are represented with a `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` structure (which *is* the same as OpenSSL).

Comment: Thanks for answer. Your sample of private key contains also public key and therefore it is a KeyPair. You can extract a public key with: openssl pkey -inform PEM -pubout -outform PEM. I was wondering if there can be a PEM with just a pure private key, with no information about public key.

Comment: @Martin Actually, what my sample contains is an `RSAPrivateKey`, as defined PKCS #1. As I stated, it *does* contain the public exponent (along with the Chinese Remainder Theorem values), to facilitate recovery of the public key. Any private key that can be read by `PEMReader` (or the OpenSSL utilities) must be in this standard format, although this can be enclosed in a PKCS #8 or PEM wrapper. Some implementations of SSH2 are unusual in that they don't use a PKCS #1 key. PEMReader will **never** return a `PrivateKey`; it will raise an exception if a private key is not in PKCS #1 format.